# How can I get the name of the request inside controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How can I get all the request name inside controller inside the `$validator->fails()`

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'patient_uname' => 'required|max:255|Alpha',
    'patient_pass' => 'required|max:255|Alpha'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {

}
```

For example if `patient_uname` fails it should display `patient_name`

Comment: `$request->patient_uname` it is.

Comment: that will display the value i want it to display patient_uname literally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the keys of all failed fields like this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd($validator->errors()->keys());
}
```

Returns this:

```
array:2 [
   0 => "patient_uname"
   1 => "patient_pass"
]
```

You can get all the error messages like this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd($validator->errors()->all());
}
```

Returns this:

```
array:2 [
   0 => "The patient uname field is required."
   1 => "The patient pass field is required."
]
```

You can get one specific field like this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd($validator->errors()->get('patient_uname'));
}
```

Returns this:

```
array:1 [
    0 => "The patient uname field is required."
]
```

Comment: I have tried echoing `$validator->errors()->keys()` but it doesnt work

Comment: I'm actually using ajax so i can't see the error but i know theres something wrong because there's internal server error in case something is wrong with the controller , dd is working but echo is not

Comment: `$validator->errors()->keys()` is an array with all failed fields, and you cannot echo an array. For an ajax call you can use `return response()->json($validator->errors());` and it should have all the information you need for the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
            $message = [
                'patient_uname.required' => 'Patient name is required',
                'patient_pass.required' => 'Patient pass is required'
            ];
            $this->validate(
                $request,
                [
                 'patient_uname' => 'required|max:255|Alpha',
                 'patient_pass' => 'required|max:255|Alpha'
                ],
                $message
            );
```

Validator takes three params

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

$messages  = ['patient_uname.required' => 'patient name is required'];
$rules     = ['patient_uname' => 'required|max:255|Alpha'];
```

In your question just pass a message array

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'patient_uname' => 'required|max:255|Alpha',
    'patient_pass' => 'required|max:255|Alpha'
], $messages);
```